# android:settypeface of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, typeface

I am making an app in which i have to set the typeface of expandable  listview.I donot know how to set type of parent and child items in expandable list view.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might not have to write your own adapter, but having your own layouts will let you control how they look.  here's a pointer to the Styles/Themes doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

if you have a custom adapter for it, set typeface in `getView()` method of the adapter, but if not, set a `ViewBinder` to your `ExpandableListView`, and there, set typeface.

use [this](http://mgmblog.com/2008/12/29/simpleadapter-viewbinders/) for knowing how to use `ViewBinder`s.